# Safari does not respect the width of div

Tags: html, css

How can I force safari to respect the width of the div?

```css
.flex {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<div class="section">

  <div class="flex">

    <div class="left" style="width:106px;"><img src="#" width="80"></div>
    <div class="right">
      <p>Text</p>
    </div>

  </div>

  <div class="flex">

    <div class="left" style="width:106px;"><img src="#" width="80"></div>
    <div class="right">
      <p>Text</p>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

I'm giving the "left" div a width 106px, and I want the next div to be at the right.

You can see Safari is measuring the width but NOT respecting it:

[image]

What I want is Safari respect that width of the left div. Thanks

Comment: try `.flex .left{ flex: 0 0 106px } .flex .right{ flex: 1 0 auto }` instead of `width: 106px` [flexbox layouts](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex) don't use the width rule, but instead use [flex-basis](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-basis)

Comment: Set `flex-shrink: 0;` to the left divs, flex-shrink is 1 by default so when the right side content is wider, it will shrink the left. Also, `nowrap` is default for a fle parent, no need to set it

Comment: Here (Safari, latest version 15.6 on MacOS 12.5) it *does*  respect the width

Answer (score 2):

Set flex-shrink: 0; to the left divs, flex-shrink is 1 by default so when the right side content is wider, it will shrink the left.

Also, `flex-wrap: nowrap` is default for a flex parent, no need to set it

```
.left {
    flex-shrink: 0;
}
```